# How to parse pydantic.SecretStr based on whether an API parameter is true

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

So I have a model class as follows:

```
class Model(BaseModel):
    token: SecretStr
    username: str
```

This model will be the response_model for my API.

I'd like my API to accept an optional parameter `def api(reveal: bool = False)`.
If the `reveal` value is `False`, the response for the above model will contain a SecretStr (`*****`) for `token`.

But if the `reveal` value is `True` in the api call, the response should contain the parsed data instead.

Is this something that's doable? Or even, is this something that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Whether it makes sense will depend on your actual use case, so someone else can't say anything sure about that. You can implement it by having two response models, one that have all the data in plain text, and one that obstructs the hidden fields:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
from pydantic import BaseModel, SecretStr
from typing import Union

app = FastAPI()


class RevealedMyData(BaseModel):
    item1: str
    secret: str

class MyData(RevealedMyData):
    secret: SecretStr


@app.get("/", response_model=Union[RevealedMyData, MyData])
def function_1(reveal: bool = False):
    data = RevealedMyData(item1='my_value', secret='my_secret')
    
    if reveal:
        return data
        
    return MyData(**data.dict())
```

If you switch them around to make the obstructed version the default you'll have to add a bit more code - in that case you'll have to create the `RevealedMyData` with the default values first, then reassign the `secret` value that you get from `MyData.get_secret_value()`.